# Calculate score difference between 2 different sheet in excel of different order

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have 2 sheets in my google spreadsheet both have some list of players and score. I need the formula to calculate the score difference for each. For eg:

In Sheet 1 we have

```
Adam - 20
Eve - 30
John - 10
```

In Sheet 2 we have

```
Adam - 35
Dave - 10
Eve - 45
John - 30
```

So, I need the difference between each person score in the Sheet 2 which would look like

```
Adam - 35 - 15
Dave - 10 - 0 (since this player was not there before)
Eve - 45 - 15
John - 30 - 20
```

I can't seem to figure out a correct formula to do this. How should I go about it?

I've tried the formula below, but it returns an error.

```
=B2-sumif('Sheet1'!A2:A90,A2==VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!A2,'Sheet1'!A2:A90,1,FALSE),'Sheet1'!B2:B90)
```

Comment: I've tried that like =B2-sumif('Sheet1'!A2:A90,A2==VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!A2,'Sheet1'!A2:A90,1,FALSE),'Sheet1'!B2:B90) but its returning error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works (if the names are in column A, and values in Column B)

In sheet2, cell C1 *(and drag for the rest of the cells)*

`=B1 - IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!$A$1:$B$3, 2,0), 0)`

Produces the following *expected* result:

[image]

Keep in mind, you need to extend the `Sheet1!` Range if you were to add more data.